# How to debug EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, debugging, ejs

There are several answers for this question, but they're all several years old and no longer relevant/safe to use.

Since EJS is rendered as html in the browser, there's no way to inspect it in the browser dev tools

The EJS.co site says that the errors/logs should show in the terminal just like node errors, but that's not the reality for me, somehow.

I used the command `npx express-generator` to bootstrap my project, and I'm wondering if there isn't a debugger of some kind in there that is overriding how EJS is supposed to send errors?

I say this because when EJS has an error, the only thing my terminal shows is something like `GET /users/dashboard 500 26.5 ms` with nothing else. And then of course the browser shows the default message for 500 errors, which isn't helpful.

I'll throw in my app.js in case someone smarter than me can see the issue there:

```js
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const rfs = require('rotating-file-stream')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('mongoose-type-url');
// const serveFavicon = require('serve-favicon');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const expressSanitizer = require('express-sanitizer');
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
// create a rotating write stream
const accessLogStream = rfs.createStream('access.log', {
    interval: '1d', // rotate daily
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'log')
});


const User = require('./models/user');

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const formsRouter = require('./routes/forms');
const companiesRouter = require('./routes/companies');
const locationsRouter = require('./routes/locations');

const app = express();
if (app.get('env') == 'development'){ require('dotenv').config(); };
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

//connect to database
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL,{
    useNewUrlParser:true, 
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex:true
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to Mongo DB')
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('error: ',err.message)
});


// view engine setup
//use ejs-locals for all ejs templates
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev', { skip: function (req,res) { return res.statusCode < 400} }));
app.use(logger('common', { stream: accessLogStream }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(expressSanitizer());
var expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000 * 6) // 6 hours
app.use(expressSession({
        secret:"surfs up brah",
        resave:false,
        saveUninitialized:false,
        name: 'sessionId',
        secure:true,
        httpOnly:true,
        expires: expiryDate
        }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    next();
});

// CHANGE: USE "createStrategy" INSTEAD OF "authenticate"
passport.use(User.createStrategy({usernameField:'personalEmail'}));

// use static authenticate method of model in LocalStrategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

//set local variables middleware
app.use(async function (req,res,next) {
    if (app.get('env') == 'development'){ req.user = await User.findOne({firstName: 'potato'}); };
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    //set default page title if one is not specified
    res.locals.title='Custom Forms';
    //set success flash message
    res.locals.success = req.session.success || "";
    //delete flash message after sending it to the page so it doesn't show again
    delete req.session.success;
    //set error flash message
    res.locals.error = req.session.error || "";
    //delete flash message after sending it to the page so it doesn't show again
    delete req.session.error;
    //continue on to the next function in the middlware/route chain
    next();
});

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/forms', formsRouter);
app.use('/companies', companiesRouter);
app.use('/locations', locationsRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


const { seedDatabase, clearDatabase, seedDefaultQuestions, clearRecentItems} = require('./seeds.js');

async function databaseInit() {
    await clearRecentItems();
    // await seedDefaultQuestions();    
    // await clearDatabase();
    await User.register({firstName: 'potato', lastName:'head',username:'potatohead', personalEmail:'test@test.com', role:'Owner'},'password');
    // await seedDatabase();
}

databaseInit();






let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 8080;
}
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("server has started, listening on port "+port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here's an example route:

```js
app.get('/dashboard', (req,res) => {
    const currentCompany = Company.findById(req.params.id);
    res.render('../views/company/profile', {currentCompany});
}
```

And some sample EJS:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1><%= currentCompany.name %></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now say I didn't wrap the `findById` call in a `try` block and it didn't find a document, then tried to render the page using an `undefined` or `null` object. The EJS file wouldn't have anything to which to refer for `currentCompany.name` (by the way, I do indeed try/catch and handle errors).

This is where the terminal just logs the simple 500 error, and refuses to load anything at all.

Another example of issues I've had with EJS:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <&- include('../../partials/header) %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here, it would throw the *exact same* 500 error because I went up one too many folders in the path for that partial. Absolutely nothing else shown anywhere.

Comment: do your other routes work? if so please add the relevant routes code. Make sure your packages are up to date, 500 almost always cause errors in console if your not catching and discarding, check NODE_ENV not production etc

Comment: Yeah other routes are fine, and the route with the EJS file is fine if I comment out EJS lines. In fact, that's been my debugging method so far: Comment everything, then uncomment one by one to see which line the problem is on. I'm assuming the 500 error is thrown because EJS rendering is done on the server, rather than on the browser, so it treats it as a generic server error.

Comment: comment out your error handler, its masking whats going on

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That finally showed me an error in the browser! So how should I have that handled differently?

Comment: your error handler is just thin, it needs to log the full object somewhere not just send a 500, also wrap it so its not used in dev, then your get standard errors to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @LawrenceCherone, the issue is the default error handler created when `npx express-generator` is used.

```js
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

Without that, the EJS error information (including line number, etc) gets displayed in the browser.